# Apache2: VirtualHost doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm having issues with redirecting a domain name to a specific folder on my server.
I'm reading the istructions from here:

These are my configuration lines:

```
#This is the default Apache2 configuration lines
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www

#This is what I've added
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/astudio/sites/mywebsite
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

However it doesn't work.. the domain just not forward the user to my website.. is there something else I have to configure ?

Comment: You tried to include a link to the instructions you're following, but the link is missing.

Comment: Patrick, this looks like a duplicate of your question at http://serverfault.com/questions/186146/how-to-configure-multiple-domains-pointing-to-different-directories-on-a-server/ .  I don't know what the protocol is here for asking the same question multiple times, but it might not be the most efficient way to get the answer!

Comment: @MadHatter ok, anyway I cannot anymore delete it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (presuming that www.mywebsite.com resolves to the ip address of your web server):

```
#This is the default Apache2 configuration lines
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/astudio/sites/mywebsite
   ServerName www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very little information to work with. Anyway...

Can you connect to the server and get the default welcome page? Do you connect using the server name or the IP address? If you use the IP address, the you will get the default page. Did you reload the configuration?

If you cannot connect, do you have the correct IP address? Is it a firewall/iptables issue? If apache listening on eth0 or only on the loopback interface?

====== EDIT

If you connect using the IP address, you get the default page, no the one you want, because the `Host:` header in the HTTP request does not match with the `ServerName` defined in your `VirtualHost`. You have to access your website specifically with `www.mywebsite.com` to access your pages (You can add aliases, though).

If you cannot connect with the name, then you have a DNS issue. A quick solution is to add the hostname and IP address to your `hosts` file. In Linux is `/etc/hosts`, in Windows it is somewhere in `\windows\system32\...` (I forget where exactly)

====== EDIT2

If you access a web site with its IP address, the `Host:` header will contain the IP address, e.g. `Host: 1.2.3.4:80`. I have not tried it but you can try add the IP address to your `VirtualHost` as a `ServerAlias`. I assume you have a dedicated IP address.

Comment: I connect to the server using the IP address.  No firewall, I dunno if apache is listening on eth0 or only on the loopback interface but it works correctly.

Comment: Added some more info in the response

Comment: Is there something I can do from Apache, or is something to solve in control panel of my hosting service or by contacting their support ?

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do name-based virtual hosting, do you have a [`NameVirtualHost *:80`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive?

Also, do you have any other `VirtualHost` sections elsewhere in your configuration that might be interfering with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, if one has Apache installed on Ubuntu (and probably other distros can also be relevant for this solution), he must pay attention to the name of the symlink in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` (if he adds links manually and not via the `a2ensite` command. A link name must always have the `.conf` extension, because only these files are included via the Include directive in the main config file.

Right now I used a `.lo` extension (which is the local domain I use) and this has cost me an extra hour of work.