# hosting multiple domain names on a single ip with apache and win-server-2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

i have a win-server-2008 vps with a single ip.
I have two domain names that I want to point to two subfoldets under htdocs.
i have tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/186146/how-to-configure-multiple-domains-pointing-to-different-directories-on-a-server) but both of domains just point to htdocs and not to any of those sub folders

currently i have this as my vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName socialms.ir
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/socialms.ir"
ErrorLog "logs/socialms.ir-error.log"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/socialms.ir/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eneka3.ir
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/eneka3.ir"
    ErrorLog "logs/eneka3.ir-error.log"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/eneka3.ir/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

whats wrong here? the dns is good and both domains point to the server's htdocs but not to specified sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

ok. so I've got the answer myself. the problem was in httpd.conf file.
the line that includes vhost file was commented out.

just changed this:

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

to this:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and then stoped and started the apache again with these commands

```
net stop apache2.4
net start apache2.4
```

and it was good to go.